# Andengine Sleep thread?

Tags: java, andengine, thread-sleep

I want to create a tiled sprite which when pressed it changes it's tile number, makes a sound and disables the button for touch for 10 seconds. 
Should I use the java thread class for this or does andengine has something more handy I can use instead?

Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

AndEngine has a Delay Modifier that could be used in combination with a ModifierListener to achieve that purpose ... something like

```
new DelayModifier(10, new IEntityModifierListener() {
    @Override
    public void onModifierStarted(IModifier<IEntity> pModifier, IEntity pItem) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    }

    @Override
    public void onModifierFinished(IModifier<IEntity> pModifier, IEntity pItem) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    }
});
```

where the "10" is the time in seconds - then use the onModifierFinished method to re-enable your tile.

Answer (score 0):

What you need is a timer here a great tutorial, read the comments also as there are other suggestions on how exactly this can be executed:[tutorial](http://www.andengine.org/forums/tutorials/using-timer-s-sprite-spawn-example-t463.html)